Aligning Figures in Columns to Match Text in Another Column
Here, I ask about alignment of images for a poster.
Flushright an image under a title but aligned beside a name/affiliation
In my actual poster (not the one here), I want to align two images so that they are centered with respect to text in an another column. Further, I'd like the left part of the first image and the right part of the second image to be aligned with the poster section blocks.
Here is my code:
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\centering
\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Here Is My Longer Concise Title For My Conference Presentation}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\Huge Here Is My Name \\[1cm]
\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\large Here Is My Affiliation 
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\vskip1cm
    
    \begin{columns}[t]

        % First column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
                Your introduction text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
                Your methods text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Second column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
                Your results text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
                Your discussion text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Third column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
                Your conclusion text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
                Your references go here.
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
                Your acknowledgements go here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Above, you'll notice the images hang over too far and are not aligned with the blue section boxes. Further, they are not centred with respect to the text in the second column. The first image should be moved up and moved slightly to the right. The second image should be moved up and slightly to the left.
Please let me know of anything's unclear.

Great ducks! ...


Horizontal alignment: In the first columns environment, the total of your columns is \textwidth, which allows no room for the space between columns and is greater than the total of 0.9\textwidth for the second block. To ensure a consistent layout, keep the total of all the column widths plus the inter-column spaces equal.
Vertical alignment:  Remove the column options for the first columns environment. You don't want T (a version of top) alignment. You want the default vertical centering.

[Image omitted because conversion will exhaust available memory, crash my editor and turn my machine into a room heater, which is unwanted in June. Copy-paste and save-as are broken due to a bug in current Okular on X11.]
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%[t]
  \centering
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Here Is My Longer Concise Title For My Conference Presentation}
  
  \vspace{2cm}
  
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\Huge Here Is My Name \\[1cm]
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\large Here Is My Affiliation 
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  
  \vskip1cm
  
  \begin{columns}[t]   
    % First column
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
        Your introduction text goes here.
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
        Your methods text goes here.
      \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    % Second column
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
        Your results text goes here.
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
        Your discussion text goes here.
      \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    % Third column
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
        Your conclusion text goes here.
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
        Your references go here.
      \end{block}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
        Your acknowledgements go here.
      \end{block}
    \end{column}    
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

EDIT
To see what will happen as you fill the poster up, you can add dummy text as filler in one or more of the columns. For example, try,
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%[t]
  \centering
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Here Is My Longer Concise Title For My Conference Presentation}
  
  \vspace{2cm}
  
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\Huge Here Is My Name \\[1cm]
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\large Here Is My Affiliation 
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  
  \vskip1cm
  
  \begin{columns}[t]   
    % First column
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
        Your introduction text goes here.
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
        Your methods text goes here.
      \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    % Second column
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
        Your results text goes here.
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
        Your discussion text goes here.
        
        \kant[1-3]
      \end{block}
    \end{column}%
    % Third column
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
        Your conclusion text goes here.
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
        Your references go here.
      \end{block}
      \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
        Your acknowledgements go here.
      \end{block}
    \end{column}    
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Thanks. Regarding point (2) and the use of T for vertical alignment, its elimination (I think) has resulted in considerable whitespace at the top of the poster. Regarding my actual logos, how can they be resized? Because the images are distinct from each other, they will likely need to be different sizes. The usual way I do it is via width=0.6\textwidth, say. Experimenting with the column widths can lead to the image being off page, however.

@compbiostats I think as you fill the poster up, the whitespace at the top will get eaten up. (I'm not sure about this, but I think so.) I don't understand what you mean about the logos. Scale them relative to the width of the columns they are in e.g. width=.9\linewidth will use 90% of the current column width. If you change the column widths, things obviously won't look aligned because your stacking rows of larger boxes atop rows of smaller ones (or vice versa).

@compbiostats Please see edit above for an example.

Ah! Will do! Thanks!
